# Как добиться симметрии исходно симметричных конструкций?

Tags: пунктуация

> И, как говорила одна моя знакомая французская маркиза, «у каждого
>   уважающего себя человека должен быть замок». И как добавил бы тут
>   всякий уважающий себя итальянец – а в городе и дворец и «дача».

*И, как говорила одна моя знакомая французская маркиза, «у каждого уважающего себя человека должен быть замок». И, как добавил бы тут всякий уважающий себя итальянец, «...а в городе – и дворец и "дача"», -*

так?

Закавыченная дача - это вилла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как говорила** одна моя знакомая французская маркиза, у каждого уважающего себя человека должен быть замок. **И как добавил бы** тут всякий уважающий себя итальянец – а в городе и дворец и «дача».

Пояснение

1. Совсем полной симметрии при оформлении лучше избегать.
2. Цитирование можно не заключать в кавычки, если считать его не дословным.

Comment: Как обосновать отсутствие запятой при повторяющихся союзах *и*?

Comment: Обычно запятая не ставится в выражениях вида "и зимой и летом", но и в других случаях это возможно. При этом  нет перечислительной интонации, а первый союз выполняет скорее роль усилительной частицы.

Comment: Я не чувствую тут усилительной частицы. Сам себе нашел ответ у Розенталя (§87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами): При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например: Были и лето и осень дождливы... (Жуковский); Кругом было и светло и зелено (Тургенев); Ой, полна, полна коробушка, есть и ситец и парча (Некрасов); Он ею и жил и дышал (А.К. Толстой); Прибрежная полоса, пересеченная мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Семушкин).

Comment: Ответ понятен, и тема известна. А вот Вы можете сказать, зачем здесь присутствует первый союз, ведь в принципе для обозначения единства  хватило бы и одного соединительного союза.

Comment: На мой взгляд, два *и* (здесь и во всех других примерах ) подчеркивают равнозначность однородных членов, обязательность их обоих.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, такая "конструкция" подойдет?

«У каждого уважающего себя человека должен быть замок» — так говорила одна моя знакомая французская маркиза. «А в городе — и дворец, и "дача"», — добавил бы тут всякий уважающий себя итальянец.

Или с небольшими изменениями в Вашем тексте, если, конечно, закавыченные фразы дословны:

И, как говорила одна моя знакомая французская маркиза, «у каждого уважающего себя человека должен быть замок». И, как добавил бы тут всякий уважающий себя итальянец, "в городе — и дворец, и «дача»".

Считаю, что "дворец" и "дачу" надобно разделить запятой.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Внешние кавычки - всегда "ёлочки", внутренние - "лапки". Перед "так" запятая отменяется (поправлено).